# Стартовая страница приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть приложение на asp.net mvc. И вот такой интересный момент. Есть стартовая страница которая является дефолтной в роут конфиг. И когда запускаешь приложение пишет только localhost... Или если перенаправляю на неё с помощь. Html.actionlink. Как добиться того что бы дефолтная страница прописывала свой полный путь как и все остальные, т.е. localhost/Controller/Action. Подскажите как такого добиться?

RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Authorization", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: @AK привёл пример моего роут конфига в вопросе. У меня там свои значения, или вы что то другое имеете в виду?

Comment: @AK а из экшен линка нашёл способ как сделать так что бы адрес был такой как мне нужно, вместо `@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index")`, написал `@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "/Index")`

Comment: @AK самое интересное если запускать приложение выбрав на редактирование View которое отвечает за стартовую страницу, тогда адрес нормально выходит, а если на любой другой файл встать, тогда запуститься без полного адреса и так только с дефолтной страницей, остальными нет такой проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в RouteСonfig.cs следующий код:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",
   "",
   new { controller = "ваш_контроллер", action = "ваше_название_action"}
);
```

Comment: Макс Жуков, попробовал ваш способ, осталось ровно то же самое.